# code to turn the wifi on/off and code to change to silent mode

Tags: android, android-emulator

i'm new to android , i want to program an application for android,
i need some help
i want a way to simply call a function that turn the wifi  on/off

and another function that change the profile from silent to general(vibration/ringing)
and from general to silent(ringing/vibration)

any help please???

public class Control{

public void turnVibrationOn(){
.......
}
public void turnVibrationOff(){
.......
}

public void turnWifiOn(){
.......
}
public void turnWifiOff(){
.......
}
}

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vibration: Use the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29) service.

```
((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE))
  .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE)
```

Wi-Fi: Use the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29) service.

```
((WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE))
  .setWifiEnabled(false)
```

(And request the proper permission.)

Comment: can u tell me how can i let my program run automatically at start up of the device??? im using emulator now i dont have device yet so can i test it on emulator?  thx

Comment: hiii can u see this plz   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366631/action-screen-on-action-screen-off-not-working